# Using Beanshell to reference parameter defined in testng.xml

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, testng

I am trying to use a parameter to determine which group of tests in my TestNG suite will be run. To do that, my testng.xml file currently looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="groupToRun" value="${valueFromJenkins}" />
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
       return groups.containsKey(groupToRun);
     ]]></script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="main.java.CWV_Functional.CWV_Functionals" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The idea is that the value of groupToRun is passed from a Jenkins job triggering this test suite. Beanshell then reads the parameter to determine which group should be run.

The problem is I do not know how to reference a parameter defined in parameter tags of the testng.xml file and cannot find any documentation showing how to do this.

Does anyone know how to use Beanshell to reference a parameter defined in the testng.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the TestNG documentation from [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)

> TestNG defines the following variables for your convenience:
>
> - `java.lang.reflect.Method` `method`:  the current test method.
> - `org.testng.ITestNGMethod` `testngMethod`:  the description of the current test method.
> - `java.util.Map<String, String>` `groups`:  a map of the groups the current test method belongs to.

So you just extract out the parameters via the `ITestNGMethod` object.

Here's how you do it

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="54335160_suite" parallel="false" verbose="2" configfailurepolicy="continue">
  <parameter name="groupToRun" value="foo"/>
  <method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
      <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
        grpParameter = testngMethod.getXmlTest().getParameter("groupToRun");
       return groups.containsKey(grpParameter);
     ]]></script>
    </method-selector>
  </method-selectors>
  <test name="54335160_test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn54335160.Qn54335160Sample">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```